# How do I restrict method to accept only object as parameter instead of Class Objects as Type Literals?

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to pass object as a parameter instead of class object as type literal. I tried many ways but did not get output.

```
public <T> List<Map<String,Object>> getUIElementsList(Class<T> requiredType) {
       doSomeThing();
       return this.fieldList;
}
```

If i'm running above code that will accept following values as parameter passing. If I have a FormBean class then

```
FormBean formBean = new FormBean();  
formBean.setUserId(252528); 
getUIElementsList(FormBean.class); //restrict this case
getUIElementsList(formBean);
```

I want that method can only accept already created intance object. I can not even use newInstance() method to create another object because i required old object instance values also.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Class<T>` itself represents some *instance*, too - this is an instance of the type `Class`, parameterized by the type `T`.

I think the best you can do is to add a check if the provided type is instance of `Class` and if yes, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public <T> List<Map<String,Object>> getUIElementsList(T value) {
    if (value instanceof Class) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Class instances are not supported");
    }
    ..
}
```

When defining type-parameters, you're only allowed to bound them by intersections of existing (families of) types, but not to apply negation on given types, like the thing you aim for, which is something like *"all types but one"*.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if you find it useful.